# Why can't I delete these array items in jq?

Tags: array, jq

Given the command:

```
echo '["tag1", "[[Super", "Duppa", "Database", "Analyst]]", "tag2"]' | jq -f ~/somefilter.jq
```

And the `jq` filter (`~/somefilter.jq`):

```
def hasOne(x): x | (startswith("[[") or endswith("]]") ); 
def looparr(r): [ r | keys[] as $i | r[$i] | select(hasOne(.)) | $i ] ; 
. as $arrray | $arrray |= .+ [ . as $arr | looparr($arr) | .[0] as $str | .[1] as $ed | $arr[$str:$ed+1] | join(" ") ] | del(.[$str:$ed+1])
```

Why doesn't `del(.[$str:$ed+1])` remove the strings that I just concatenated together into their own item?

Instead I get the following error:

```
jq: error: str/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 3:
. as $arrray | $arrray |= .+ [ . as $arr | looparr($arr) | .[0] as $str | .[1] as $ed | $arr[$str:$ed+1] | join(" ") ] | del(.[$str:$ed+1])
jq: error: ed/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 3:
. as $arrray | $arrray |= .+ [ . as $arr | looparr($arr) | .[0] as $str | .[1] as $ed | $arr[$str:$ed+1] | join(" ") ] | del(.[$str:$ed+1])
```

If I drop `| del(.[$str:$ed+1])` at the end, and replace it with `| .`, my output becomes:

```json
[
  "tag1",
  "[[Super",
  "Duppa",
  "Database",
  "Analyst]]",
  "tag2",
  "[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]"
]
```

My desired output is more like:

```json
[
  "tag1",
  "tag2",
  "[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]"
]
```

When I try adding constants it works just fine, but that doesn't make my script very malleable (and it may not be anyway at this point).

Is there any reason I can't access `$str` and `$ed`?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that these variables are out of scope, as they are bound whilst inside a `[]`. I'm a `jq` neophyte, but the following, which duplicates the code, seems to give the right answer for you to build upon:

```
 . as $arr |
 looparr($arr) | 
 .[0] as $str |
 .[1] as $ed |
 $arr |
 del(.[$str:$ed+1])
+ [
 . as $arr |
 looparr($arr) | 
 .[0] as $str |
 .[1] as $ed |
 $arr[$str:$ed+1] |
 join(" ")
]
```

Comment: Oh they are scoped within the `[]` okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your `jq` expression has to do with the scoping of the variable `$str` and `$ed`, [as already mentioned by meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371088/116858).  They are defined within an array expression and therefore scoped within that expression.  When you call `del(.[$str:$ed+1])`, they are no longer in scope.

I provide an alternative solution using `reduce` below, which does not require defining any extra functions:

```
reduce .[] as $item ([];
        if      isempty(.[])
        or      (last | startswith("[[") | not)
        or      (last | endswith("]]"))
        then
                # Current item is to be added to the list
                # as a separate list item.
                .       += [$item]
        else
                # Current item is to be appended to the last
                # list item (with a delimiting space).
                last    += " " + $item
        end
)
```

This starts with an empty result array.  The implicit loop of `reduce` then iterates over the input array.  Each element of the input array is either added to the resulting array as is (the first `if` branch) or appended to its last element (the `else` branch).

The current element is added to the result array, rather than appended to the last element of it, if the result array is empty or if its last element does not start with `[[` or if it ends with `]]`.

Testing:

```bash
$ jq . file
[
  "tag1",
  "[[Super",
  "Duppa",
  "Database",
  "Analyst]]",
  "tag2"
]
```

```bash
$ jq -f script file
[
  "tag1",
  "[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]",
  "tag2"
]
```

---

Running with `| debug` after the `end` of the `if` statement within `reduce` to output the result array after each step:

```bash
$ jq -f script file
["DEBUG:",["tag1"]]
["DEBUG:",["tag1","[[Super"]]
["DEBUG:",["tag1","[[Super Duppa"]]
["DEBUG:",["tag1","[[Super Duppa Database"]]
["DEBUG:",["tag1","[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]"]]
["DEBUG:",["tag1","[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]","tag2"]]
[
  "tag1",
  "[[Super Duppa Database Analyst]]",
  "tag2"
]
```